# Set element value to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line of jQuery where I am setting the value of an element to value of an array like this:

```
$("#Issue").val(rik(0));
```

But all I get is a JavaScript error:

> Function Expected.

I tried:

```
var RIK = rik(0);
$("#Issue").val(RIK);
```

Same Error. I know I've done this before, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `rik(0)` is not how you reference an index of an array. It is square bracket notation..

Answer (score 0):

If `rik` is an array, like you said in your question, you're going to have to access it using `[]` brackets. 
`$("#Issue").val(rik[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Array items in JavaScript are accessed with square brackets `[]`, not parentheses `()`, so to store the first item in the `value` like you're trying to do in your first line, you need to change it to:

```
$("#Issue").val(rik[0]);
```

But if you want to store the whole array in the `value`, you can convert the items to a string and join them using the `join()` method:

```
$("#Issue").val(rik.join());
```

By default, this will join the elements using a comma as a separator. If you want to use another separator, you can pass it to the `join()` method. For example, if you want to use the pipe bar `|`:

```
$("#Issue").val(rik.join("|"));
```